# In Java, how to interpret the UTF-8 bytes of a String?

Tags: java, utf-8, byte

The Java `byte` type is signed, with the scope from -128 to 127 (inclusive). What a terrible design it is!

Now, I want to get the UTF-8 representation of a Java `String`. As I understand, the UTF-8 representation is a sequence of unsigned bytes (with the scope from 0 to 255, inclusively). The `String` class in Java provides the following method, which seems to be able to provide the UTF-8 representation of a `String`:

```
byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
```

However, as you can see, this method returns an array of the Java `byte` type. So, how should I interpret this array?

For example, if `s` is a `String`, and `bArray` is the returned array of `s.getBytes("UTF-8")`, then:

1. If `bArray[0]` is -100, then what is the first unsigned byte (in the scope of 0 to 255) of this UTF-8 representation?
2. If the first unsigned byte (in the scope of 0 to 255) of this UTF-8 representation is 200, then what is `bArray[0]`?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a byte to an int in the range 0-255? `0xff & theByte`.

Comment: A `byte` is 8 bits. Java interprets it as an 8-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer, but you can interpret it as you wish. To interpret it as an unsigned 8-bit integer, try this: `int value = (int)(b & 0xFF);`

Comment: @Jesper (nit: the `(int)` isn't necessary: binary numeric promotion makes `b & 0xFF` an `int` already).

Answer (score 1):

From int to signed byte

```
int i = 200;                    // some value between 0 and 255
byte b = (byte) i;              // 8 bits representing that value
```

From signed byte to int

```
byte b = -100;                   // 8 bits representing a value between -128 and 127
int i = b & 0xFF;               // an int representing the value but in range [0..255]
```